# Spring security Angular Post not supported

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

i am working on todo list it is working ok but when i add spring security to project and click on add it gives

> 2016-07-10 04:32:34.441  WARN 6692 --- [nio-8080-exec-8]
>   o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not
>   supported

any solution to this problem

SpringWebSecurityConfig :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDS;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/images/*").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/template/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDS).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDS;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TaskController {

    @RequestMapping("/task")
    public String task() {

        return "task";
    }

}
```

task.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="taskManagerApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <!--IE Compatibility Meta-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <!--first Mobile Meta-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <title>Tasks</title>


    <!--css fontawesome jb-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>


    <!--My Css File-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/task.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>

    <!--if IT IE 9-->
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.14"
            src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.14"
            src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main-p.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugin.js"></script>

    <!--endif-->


</head>
<body>

<!--==============Start Menu==========-->

<div class="row">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebar  col-sm-6 col-md-2" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Todx</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/dashboard">&#35; Dashboard<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                                                 class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="/chat">Chat<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                  class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity fa fa-comments"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/task">Tasks<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                   class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity fa fa-bolt"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/files">Files<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                    class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity fa fa-paperclip"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/calendar">Calendar<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                          class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity fa fa-calculator"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/addtocalendar">Add to calendar<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                                      class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity fa fa-calendar-o
"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/hangout">Hangout<span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                        class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity fa fa-video-camera

"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <span
                                class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;"
                                                           class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--==========End Section Menu=========-->


    <!--==========Start Section Project=========-->

    <div class="right-side col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-10">
        <!--==========Start Navbar=========-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <a id="nav-brand" class="navbar-brand " href="#"><span
                                                class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse horizon-nav">
                                        <ul id="home-page" class="nav navbar-nav ">
                                            <li id="activ"><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li id="profile"><a id="account" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ">
                                                <img class="img-circle img-responsive"
                                                     src="/images/1.png"
                                                     style="margin-left:5; width: 50px;display: inline-flex "/></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="logout"><a href="/logout">logout</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--==========End Navbar=========-->
        <!--==========Start Divs=========-->
        <!-- this is main Div that contain navbar divs  -->

        <div id="content" class="yellow col-xs-12">

            <!-- add task here !! -->
            <div ng-controller="taskManagerController">
                <div id="task-panel" class="fadein fadeout showpanel panel" ng-show="toggle">
                    <div class="panel-heading ">
                        <!--<i class="panel-title-icon fa fa-tasks"></i>-->
                        <div class="panel-heading-controls">
                            <i class="panel-title-icon fa fa-tasks"></i>

                            <span class="panel-title">Recent Tasks</span>
                            <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle" class="btn-md btn-panel ">Add New Task</button>
                            <button class="btn-md btn-panel  " ng-click="archiveTasks()"> Clear completed
                                <!--ng-confirm-click="Would you like to archive completed tasks?">Clear completed tasks-->
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div style="text-align: left" class="task" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <span ng-if="task.taskPriority=='HIGH'" class="priority priority-red">
                    {{task.taskPriority}}
                </span>
                <span ng-if="task.taskPriority=='MEDIUM'" class="priority priority-yellow">
                    {{task.taskPriority}}
                </span>
                <span ng-if="task.taskPriority=='LOW'" class="priority priority-green">
                    {{task.taskPriority}}
                </span>
                            <div class="action-checkbox">
                                <input id="{{task._links.self.href}}" type="checkbox" value="{{task._links.self.href}}"
                                       ng-checked="selection.indexOf(task._links.self.href) > -1"
                                       ng-click="toggleSelection(task._links.self.href)"/>
                                <label for="{{task._links.self.href}}"></label>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-if="task.taskStatus=='COMPLETED'">
                                <a href="#" class="checkedClass">
                                    {{task.taskName}}
                                    <span class="action-status">{{task.taskStatus}}</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: left" ng-if="task.taskStatus=='ACTIVE'">
                                <a href="#" class="uncheckedClass">
                                    {{task.taskName}}
                                    <span class="action-status">{{task.taskStatus}}</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="add-task-panel" class="fadein fadeout addpanel panel" ng-hide="toggle">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-heading-controls">
                            <i class="panel-title-icon fa fa-plus"></i>
                            <span class="panel-title panel-title2">Add Task</span>
                            <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle" class="btn-panel">Show All Tasks</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="task">
                            <table class="add-task">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Task Name:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="taskName" class="form-group"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Task Description:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="taskDesc" class="form-group"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Task Status:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select ng-model="taskStatus"
                                                ng-options="status as status for status in statuses">
                                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Task Priority:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select ng-model="taskPriority"
                                                ng-options="priority as priority for priority in priorities">
                                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><br/>
                                        <button ng-click="addTask()" class="btn-panel-big"
                                        >Add New Task
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--==========End Divs=========-->
    </div>

    <!--==========End Section Project=========-->


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var taskManagerModule = angular.module('taskManagerApp', ['ngAnimate']);

taskManagerModule.controller('taskManagerController', function ($scope,$http) {

    var urlBase="";
    $scope.toggle=true;
    $scope.selection = [];
    $scope.statuses=['ACTIVE','COMPLETED'];
    $scope.priorities=['HIGH','LOW','MEDIUM'];
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    function findAllTasks() {
        //get all tasks and display initially
        $http.get(urlBase + '/tasks/search/findByTaskArchived?archivedfalse=0').
            success(function (data) {
                if (data._embedded != undefined) {
                    $scope.tasks = data._embedded.tasks;
                } else {
                    $scope.tasks = [];
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.tasks[i].taskStatus == 'COMPLETED') {
                        $scope.selection.push($scope.tasks[i].taskId);
                    }
                }
                $scope.taskName="";
                $scope.taskDesc="";
                $scope.taskPriority="";
                $scope.taskStatus="";
                $scope.toggle='!toggle';
            });
    }

    findAllTasks();

    //add a new task
    $scope.addTask = function addTask() {
        if($scope.taskName=="" || $scope.taskDesc=="" || $scope.taskPriority == "" || $scope.taskStatus == ""){
            alert("Insufficient Data! Please provide values for task name, description, priortiy and status");
        }
        else{
         $http.post(urlBase + '/tasks', {
             taskName: $scope.taskName,
             taskDescription: $scope.taskDesc,
             taskPriority: $scope.taskPriority,
             taskStatus: $scope.taskStatus
         }).
          success(function(data, status, headers) {
             alert("Task added");
             var newTaskUri = headers()["location"];
             console.log("Might be good to GET " + newTaskUri + " and append the task.");
             // Refetching EVERYTHING every time can get expensive over time
             // Better solution would be to $http.get(headers()["location"]) and add it to the list
             findAllTasks();
            });
        }
    };

    // toggle selection for a given task by task id
      $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(taskUri) {
        var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(taskUri);

        // is currently selected
        // HTTP PATCH to ACTIVE state
        if (idx > -1) {
          $http.patch(taskUri, { taskStatus: 'ACTIVE' }).
          success(function(data) {
              alert("Task unmarked");
              findAllTasks();
            });
          $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
        }

        // is newly selected
        // HTTP PATCH to COMPLETED state
        else {
          $http.patch(taskUri, { taskStatus: 'COMPLETED' }).
          success(function(data) {
              alert("Task marked completed");
              findAllTasks();
            });
          $scope.selection.push(taskUri);
        }
      };


    // Archive Completed Tasks
      $scope.archiveTasks = function archiveTasks() {
          $scope.selection.forEach(function(taskUri) {
              if (taskUri != undefined) {
                  $http.patch(taskUri, { taskArchived: 1});
              }
          });
          alert("Successfully Archived");
          console.log("It's risky to run this without confirming all the patches are done. when.js is great for that");
          findAllTasks();
      };

});

//Angularjs Directive for confirm dialog box
taskManagerModule.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
         return {
             link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                 var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                 var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                 element.bind('click',function (event) {
                     if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                         scope.$eval(clickAction);
                     }
                 });
             }
         };
 }]);
```

Notice that the get it working and it retrive all tasks but the post give 405 in the network developer chrome console and i think it is in spring security it worked before on spring security but i do not know what i did and now it is not working

Comment: What is the URL where you are sending the POST? And can you post the controller that handles that request?

Comment: i am posting it in angular to /tasks

Comment: Did you try setting the accept header? Your browser may be setting the accept header and your header may not be saying that it can accept that.

Comment: i can not understand

Answer (score 0):

By default, it’s assumed all incoming requests to URLs are of the HTTP GET kind. To differentiate the mapping by HTTP request type, we need to explicitly specify the HTTP request method in the @RequestMapping declaration

If you are trying to POST to this URL, Spring will reject it.

Try changing your annotation to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String task() {

    return "task";
}
```

If you already have a external reference for the current GET method, you can still create an additional definition for the POST method, so that both can coexist. You only have to assign them different Java method names like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String task() {

    return "task";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/task", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postTask() {

    return "task";
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

If your controller is intended to receive Ajax calls, you need to add additional annotations (like @ResponseBody) to let Spring MVC know that this is an ajax capable controller / method

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/task", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String task() {

    return "task";
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try the following. Truly, I don't know if Spring Security enforces parameters versus method signatures, but it may be your case.

```
public String task(@RequestParam(value = "taskName") String taskName,
                   @RequestParam(value = "taskDescription") String  taskDescription,
                   @RequestParam(value = "taskPriority") String taskPriority, 
                   @RequestParam(value = "taskStatus") String taskStatus) {

    return "task";
}
```

Comment: No it is not working plus it was working before adding spring security

Comment: This is not a spring security issue, as those return 401 error (forbidden). Please see update

Comment: it is returning 405
error
:
"Method Not Allowed"
exception
:
"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException"
message
:
"Request method 'POST' not supported"
path
:
"/tasks"
status
:
405
timestamp
:
"2016-07-10T03:17:00.497+0000"

Comment: Are you sending parameters as JSON to your "/task" controller ?

Comment: iam not sending it to /task controller i use mongo data rest with angular 
i use /task in the controller to just retrive the page

Comment: Please add the JS code you use to retrieve the page

Comment: $http.post(urlBase + '/tasks', {
             taskName: $scope.taskName,
             taskDescription: $scope.taskDesc,
             taskPriority: $scope.taskPriority,
             taskStatus: $scope.taskStatus
         }).

Comment: You are actually sending 'taskName', 'taskDescription', 'taskPriority' and 'taskStatus' via POST to /task. This parameters have to be present on the method signature of your controller

Comment: but it is working ok without adding the spring security config i tried it

Comment: Mmmm I cannot see the relationship unless Spring Security enforces that the parameters you are sending actually matches a controller that receives those parameters. Try with update 2

Comment: not working to Required String parameter 'taskName' is not present
the problem is the same code is running 100% without using spring security

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116904/discussion-between-cristian-meneses-and-ibrahim-mohamed).

Comment: Please join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116904/discussion-between-cristian-meneses-and-ibrahim-mohamed

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem i was making another controller get to /{files}
which conflict with the post method of the angular